# Pattern for chained if statements

Tags: c#, design-patterns, if-statement

I'm building a guitar chord finder app.  I use a multi-dimensional array to represent the fretboard.  Each element in the array is represented by a FretSpace struct which has a string property 'Note'.  In order to initialize the note properties across the fretboard, I pass details of the guitar string to work on, along with the fretboard.  This work is done in a GuitarTuner class.  Here is the FretSpace class:-

```
public struct FretSpace : IPlottable, IResourceConsumer
{
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public int XPos { get; set; }

    public int YPos { get; set; }

    public string ResourceName { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}] Note:{1} XPos:{2} YPos{3} ResourceName:{4}",
            GetType().Name, Note, XPos, YPos, ResourceName);
    }
}
```

The guitar tuner class tunes one string at a time.  In this case, tuning means to initialise every FretSpace Note property with the correct musical note for that fret position.  In the TuneString method, I check the string we are working on and return a list of notes to apply to the chosen string.  I look at my code and it smells big time.  here is the offending portion of the TuneString method:-

```
public void TuneString(GuitarString stringToTune, FretSpace[,] fretboard)
    {
        List<string> notes = null;

        if (stringToTune == GuitarString.ELow)
        {
            notes = _scaleGenerator.GetScale(Scale.E).ToList();
        }
        if (stringToTune == GuitarString.A)
        {
            notes = _scaleGenerator.GetScale(Scale.A).ToList();
        }
        if (stringToTune == GuitarString.D)
        {
            notes = _scaleGenerator.GetScale(Scale.D).ToList();
        }
        if (stringToTune == GuitarString.G)
        {
            notes = _scaleGenerator.GetScale(Scale.G).ToList();
        }
        if (stringToTune == GuitarString.B)
        {
            notes = _scaleGenerator.GetScale(Scale.B).ToList();
        }
        if (stringToTune == GuitarString.EHigh)
        {
            notes = _scaleGenerator.GetScale(Scale.E).ToList();
        } //carry on and tune the string using the notes we returned
```

I am no design pattern master but I am rapidly acquiring a keen nose for code smells.  Is there a better way to do this given that the same method is being called every time but with just a different parameter.  I looked at Command.  Doesn't seem to apply where a value is returned but correct me if I am wrong.  I also looked at factory but this seems concerned with returning a family of objects, which in this case doesn't apply.  I'v searched stack overflow for the best part of an hour and can't seem to find a relevent example.  Can anyone help.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the code smell you're talking of? Btw, use `else if` or `switch`.

Comment: I'm at that stage where I constantly question my design decisions.  I'm an amateur and it just doesn't look or feel right to me.  If there is a better way of doing things i'd like to know.  Likewise if there is nothing wrong with this design, I also need to know.  else if switch statement suggestion noted thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally would create a `Dictionary<GuitarString, Scale>` and store your mappings between a string and a scale in there. Then you can simply lookup the string in there to get the scale.

e.g.

```
var stringToScaleMap = new Dictionary<GuitarString, Scale>
                           { 
                               { GuitarString.ELow, Scale.E }
                               , { GuitarString.A, Scale.A }
                               // etc...
                           }

var scale = stringToScaleMap[stringToTune];
notes = _scaleGenerator.GetScale(scale).ToList();
```

You could store the map in configuration or simply hardcode it somewhere in your project. As the mapping is unlikely to change the latter is probably the simplest option.

Comment: Looks great to me, and in the absence of any other alternative suggestions will give it a go.  Thanks.